# How to compile g++ on windows using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, boost, g++

I have successfully installed OpenCV and Boost Library and config in my Visual Studio. I want to run a project ([here](https://github.com/aperrau/DetectText)). How can I compile this project with g++ on windows?

> g++ -o DetectText TextDetection.cpp FeaturesMain.cpp -lopencv_core
>   -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -I/path/to/current/directory where /path/to/current/directory is replaced with the absolute path to the
>   current directory.

I am very new and please help me step by step to run this  project using VC++

Thank you so much.

Comment: you probably don't need boost at all

Comment: have you any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix g++ and MSVS without a lot of pain. Use a different IDE, like Qt Creator (with CMake), Eclipse, or Code::Blocks.

You seem to know how to compile from the commandline, so why not just do that?

Comment: g++ is not recognized in windows cmd? can you help me?

Comment: @Jules: You need to add `<wherever you installed MinGW(-w64)>\bin` to PATH by doing `set PATH=<somewhere>\bin;%PATH%`.